# ChunksOfCountCollection in swift algorithms

Tags: swift, algorithm

In swift algorithms, how to get the second items of a chunked collection?

```
let a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
let chunked = a.chunks(ofCount: 2) //["a", "b"] ["c", "d"] ["e"]
```

Now I want to get the ["c", "d"]

I can get the range using

```
chunked.index(chunked.startIndex, offsetBy: 1) //Index(baseRange: Range(2..<4))
```

But after that, I don't know how to get the exact result.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already got the index. Just use the subscript syntax to access the collection:

```
chunked[chunked.index(chunked.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)]
```

This will give you an `ArraySlice<String>`. Printing this will give you `["c", "d"]`.

Comment: That works! I didn't realize I could use subscript. Thanks a lot!